# Android how to make vertical swipeable button like present on incoming call screen

Tags: android, swipe, android-button

I am trying to to take input of user based on swipeable button vertically for agreeing or disagreeing. What approach should i follow?

Comment: I think your Question is already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures/12938787#12938787

Comment: i am talking about UI part like arrow up with answer text on the button